# Laravel User update returns NULL

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to update an existing User Model.

```
$user = \Auth::user();
$user_data_array = ['email' => 'email@domain.com'];
return $user->update($user_data_array);
```

When this code is executed, the returned value is `null`, but the model is successfully updated as expected. I dug a bit deeper into `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php` and found that the `update($attributes, $options)` function calls `$this->fill($attributes)->save($options)`.

When I `dd($attributes)` while inside the `update()` function, `$attributes` shows correctly as an array with the email. But, when I `dd($attributes)` from inside the `fill()` function, `$attributes` is an empty array. Somehow, `$attributes` seems to be getting lost between the two.

The same thing happens when I try to use the `save()` function. The model is successfully updated, but the function returns `null`.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: it also happen if you do: $user->email="email@example.com"; return $user->save(); ?

Comment: Yes, it happens with both `save()` and `update()`

Comment: What makes you think the method is returning `null`?

Comment: I'm returning the value as shown in the code above. It's returning null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue.

**TL;DR; check if the `save()` method is being overridden and make sure the overriding method returns the result of `parent::save()`**

While debugging the `save()` method I logged both the value to-be-returned and the value once returned. `true` and `null` respectively... it made no sense. "Somewhere in the code someone must have overridden the save method and forgot to return `parent::save()`..." I thought but just couldn't find it. It took me a while to realize it was a trait from a package used for ACL: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust. The code in the master branch is ok but the code I was using was from release 1.7.0. This release had this issue, which was reported and there was a pull request.

My user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,
        EntrustUserTrait;
}
```

The EntrustUserTrait for release 1.7.0

```
trait EntrustUserTrait {
...
    public function save(array $options = [])
    {   //both inserts and updates
        parent::save($options);
        Cache::tags(Config::get('entrust.role_user_table'))->flush();
    }
}
```

You see the problem? there is no `return`... hence the `null`. So to correct this you can:

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{   //both inserts and updates
    $saved = parent::save($options);
    Cache::tags(Config::get('entrust.role_user_table'))->flush();
    return $saved;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code should look like this:

```
<?php
  $user = Auth::user();
  $user->email = "test@test.com";
  return $user->save();
?>
```